# Passing parameters: Difference between array and *&array and &array[0] in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Is the following equivalent in C?

The differences are only in the last line (`AnyFunction`).

**A**

```
static void AnyFunction(unsigned char *array);
unsigned char array[32] = "";

AnyFunction(array);
```

**B**

```
static void AnyFunction(unsigned char *array);
unsigned char array[32] = "";

AnyFunction(*&array);
```

**C**

```
static void AnyFunction(unsigned char *array);
unsigned char array[32] = "";

AnyFunction(&array[0]);
```

In case any of these are equivalent, does the same apply for C++?

See the question and code exampled above.

Comment: Fine question, but I just want to add that using `std::array` or `std::vector` in C++ (that both know their sizes) is much safer and easier than messing around with C-style arrays (basically just forget they exist in the language).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The end result is the same, although how they each get there is slightly different.

In the first case:

```
AnyFunction(array);
```

`array` decays to a pointer to its first member when being passed to a function, specifically from type `unsigned char [32]` to `unsigned char *` which matches what the function expects.

In the second case:

```
AnyFunction(*&array);
```

The address of `array` is taken, giving us an expression of type `unsigned char (*)[32]` i.e. a pointer to an array, then the `*` operator dereferences this pointer resulting in an expression which is an array with type `unsigned char [32]`.  Then as in the first case this array decays to a pointer to its first element.

In the last case:

```
AnyFunction(&array[0]);
```

The array index operator gives us an lvalue which is the first element of the array, and the `&` operator gives us the address of that element, and that result is passed to the function.

In all three cases, the function is passed a pointer to the first element of `array`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! 

Comment: Note that **A** and **B** are always the same, even in C++, but **C** can be different there since the array-to-pointer conversion is more easily avoided.

Answer (score 1):

The three cases are equivalent:

1. Legally, the first (the array name itself) is *by definition* the address of the first element of the array, so the value itself in an expression is a pointer to one array element (`unsigned char *` type).
2. in the second case, you use the array's address `&array`, which is of type `unsigned char (*)[32]` (pointer to an array of 32 unsigned char elements), and when dereferenced by `*` it converts into the array itself, with type `unsigned char [32]` (array of 32 unsigned chars) so when used in an expression, it becomes (by the same explanation in 1.) a pointer to the first element of the array, resulting in an `unsigned char *` pointer value.
3. in the C case, `&array[0]`, you use exactly the definition in 1. This is the address of the first element, which is, by definition the array name itself when used in an expression.  `array` and `&array[0]` are exactly the same thing (*by definition*) when found in an expression (not involving the `sizeof` operator).

Comment: (1) is a bit inaccurate. Arrays are implicitly converted to pointers in some cases, but they're not pointers by default. Otherwise you e.g. wouldn't be able to have references to arrays, or `sizeof` would work differently on them.

Comment: As K&R states in it's first edition book, an array name by itself in an expression is _by definition_ the address of its first element (a pointer rvalue to an array element, the first one)  The only exception relates to the `sizeof` operator applied to an array object, that gives the total size of the array object itself.   I don't try to be accurate, I try to be understandable by the questioneer, which probably is not a language lawyer or a compiler writer.

Comment: If they say that, then they're wrong. The wording is up to you, of course, but this is somewhat confusing. (If it's a pointer, then why `&array` is not `int **`, and why compiles at all if it's an rvalue; and so on.)

Comment: a pointer to an array of arrays is not the same as  a double pointer, I'm afraid, and I have not said anything contradicting this.

Comment: What I'm saying is, if `array` is an rvalue pointer, then you can't take its address (as it's an rvalue), and, ignoring that, its address would have type `int **`, which it doesn't.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, if an array were an lvalue you could say `array = some_other_address;`, and you cannot.  An array cannot be used in any way in C as a whole object (except to take it's size, by means of the `sizeof` operator, or its address by `&`)  you cannot use it as an lvalue, because it's not placeable in the left side of an `=` assignment operator.  The only meaning given to its name in an expression is to produce an rvalue pointer to it's first element.  You can take it's address, and its address (by means of the `&` operator) is another (differently typed) rvalue pointer.

Comment: Not all lvalues can be assigned to, e.g. consider `const int x = 42;`. C++ provides a way to check the value category: `decltype((x))` will return `T &` for lvalues (and `T &&` for xvalues, `T` for prvalues). I guess C++ has way more cases where arrays don't decay to pointers, and this distinction matters more there.

Comment: I'm not talking about C++ which has an overhelming list of different cases to consider due to operator overloading.  I used K&R explanation, from a time in which C++ was not yet existent.